# PIP Install pyodbc Could not find a version

Tags: python, pip, pyodbc

I am installing pyodbc using pip but system reply could not found a version.

I believe pyodbc still exist from pypi.python.org.

[image]

Please see the pic I attached for error.

I have pip 9.0.1 version and python 3.5 installed

Also, with the help menu, I don't see --allow-external and --allow-unverified available.

[image]

Comment: [pyodbc download](https://code.google.com/archive/p/pyodbc/downloads) and install.

Comment: Ohkay! if you see the errors, do you see **`ConnectTimeoutError`**, may be you should check that first.

Comment: It could have been a transient problem with the PyPI server(s). I just did `pip install pyodbc` and got the latest version (4.0.15).

Answer (score 0):

Try installing it from URL directly:

```
pip install https://storage.googleapis.com/google-code-archive-downloads/v2/code.google.com/pyodbc/pyodbc-3.0.7.zip
```

Latest version: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyodbc/4.0.15

Download the .whl file install using pip

Comment: Version 3.0.7 is very old.

Comment: That's great, so you got it working ? If yes, you can add that info to my answer please.